# Tableau(Calculated Field)

Tags: tableau-api

[image: Tableau sample data]

I have uploaded the sample data above.

So in Tableau, I want to create calculated field. For example, if the ID is same and that ID has already complete the calls, then the another id with the same id should be named complete too, so the final output should be:

[image]

I have 1000 of id's like that. Any help would be appreciated. If you don't understand the questions, let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a calculated field. Convert the Complete and Incomplete values to a number and take the max per ID.

[CallStatus]

IF {FIXED [ID]:MAX(IF [Calls] = "Complete" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)} = 1 THEN "Complete" ELSE "Incomplete" END